# Чтение из текстуры D3DPOOL_DEFAULT

Tags: c#, c++, direct3d, текстура

Есть текстура, созданная следующим вызовом функции:

```
direct3d_device->CreateTexture(
                                width, 
                                height,
                                1,
                                D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,
                                get_pixel_format(),
                                D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
                                &direct3d_texture
                              );
```

Как известно, текстуры созданные с флагом `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` нельзя блокировать для чтения и записи.

Необходимо прочитать часть текстуры (писать не нужно). Существует ли способ обхода этого ограничения? Создать текстуру с флагом `D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET | D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC` не удалось.

Comment: Можно скопировать из текстуры D3DPOOL_DEFAULT в другую текстуру созданную с флагом D3DPOOL_MANAGED которую потом можно заблокировать и прочесть - но этот способ довольно медленный.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Самый медленный способ - использовать LoadSurfaceFromSurface для копирования в D3DPOOL_MANAGED.
Самый быстрый (у меня работает в 100-200 раз быстрее первого способа) - сначала с помощью GetRenderTargetData скопировать в D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, а затем уже залочить и считать или, если надо - скопировать в d3dpool_managed.

Comment: Видел GetRenderTargetData но остановил тот момент что она копирует целиком текстуру в системную память, в то время когда мне нужен был маленький регион большой текстуры.